# How to apply standardization to train and test datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Let's say I have a `10` feature dataset `X` of shape `[100, 10]` and a `y`target dataset of shape `[100, 1]`.
For example, after splitting the two with `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` I obtained:

- `X_train: [70, 10]`
- `X_test: [30, 10]`
- `y_train: [70, 1]`
- `y_test: [30, 1]`

What is the correct way of apply standardization?

I've tried with:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train_std = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

but then if I try to predict using a model, when I try to inverse the scaling for looking at the MAE, I have an error

```
from sklearn import linear_model
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
y_pred_std = lr.predict(X_test_std)

y_pred = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred_std) # error here
```

I have also another question. Since I have the target values, should I use

```
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

X_train_std = scaler.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
X_test_std = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

instead of the first code block?

Do I have to apply the transformation also to the `y_train` and `y_test` datasets? I am a bit confuse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StandardScaler` is supposed to be used on the feature matrix X only.

So all the `fit`, `transform` and `inverse_transform` methods just need your X.

Note that after you fit the model, you can access the following attributes:

1. `mean_`: mean of each feature in `X_train`
2. `scale_`: standard deviation of each feature in `X_train`

The `transform` method does `(X[i, col] - mean_[col] / scale_[col])` for each sample `i`. Whereas the `inverse_transform` method `(X[i, col] * scale_[col] + mean_[col])` for each sample `i`.

Comment: But in case of `y` is made of values  and not categories, how can I calc the MAE if `y_pred` and `y_test` are on different scales?

Comment: They are not in different scales, you do not transform the targets `y`, you only transform the features `X`. The goal of scaling `X` is to make it easier for your regressor to find the mapping between the features and the target. Note that you could also apply a transformation to targets (from a theoretical point of you) but that is not what `StandardScalar` does.